# How to package a python program for distribution on a network

Tags: python

I'm not sure if I'm even asking this question correctly. I just built my first real program and I want to make it available to people in my office. I'm not sure if I will have access to the shared server, but I was hoping I could simply package the program (I hope I'm using this term correctly) and upload it to a website for my coworkers to download.

I know how to zip a file, but something tells me it's a little more complicated than that :) In fact, some of the people in my office who need the program installed do not have python on their computers already, and I would rather avoid asking everyone to install python before downloading my .py files from my hosting server.

So, is there an easy way to package my program, along with python and the other dependencies, for simple distribution from a website? I tried searching for the answer but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. Oh, and since this is the first time I have done this- are there any precautions I need to take when sharing these files so that everything runs smoothly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) can package your Python program.

<strike>Both are actively maintained.</strike>  PyInstaller is actively maintained.  py2exe has not been updated for at least a year.  I've used each with success.

Also there is [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) which I have not used.

Comment: py2exe doesn't seem to have been updated in over a year (although of course it may still work). PyInstaller, on the other hand, does seem to be actively maintained.

Comment: @Thomas K.  Thanks for reminding me.  I switched to PyInstaller because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.py2exe.org/